# Is my laptop good for speakers?

Tags: speakers, acer-aspire

I got an Acer Aspire A715-71G and looking to buy a set of speakers with an impendance of 4 Ohms. How do I know if my laptop is good for them ,or if it is powerfull enough?

Comment: Just curious, why the requirement of 4 Ohms?

Comment: Not requirement ,I want to know if the laptop is powerfull enough ,or if they are compatible

Answer (score 1):

Computers generally don't have built-in amps, so you'd need a powered system including an amp, not just speakers.